# Offset this scroll-to-element function

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can offset this scroll-to function so that it stops 80px above the element it's scrolling to?

I have a fixed header, which is 80px in height, and when I scroll to an element the header obscures some of the content.

```
    function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
    }
    var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
    var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

    $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
      var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
      if (  locationPath == thisPath
      && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
      && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
        var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
        if (target) {
          var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
          $(this).click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 700, function() {
              location.hash = target;
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });

    // use the first element that is "scrollable"
    function scrollableElement(els) {
      for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
        var el = arguments[i],
            $scrollElement = $(el);
        if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
          return el;
        } else {
          $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
          var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
          $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
          if (isScrollable) {
            return el;
          }
        }
      }
      return [];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

`var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;`

to

`var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 80;`

Or better yet

`var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - $('#your-header-id').outerHeight();`

That should do the trick and be a bit more robust should you change the height of the header.

**Edit:**

To get round your problem you should change the ids of each of the sections to `section-about` / `section-services` / etc. Then you will have to do some string replacement:

```
var targetId = $target.attr('id').replace('#','#section-');

var targetOffset = $(targetId).offset().top - 80;
```

`$target` at the moment will be the hash in the url, so `#about`. The above code will just replace the `#` with `#section-`. Then you will be able to carry on as usual by getting the top `offset()` of `$('#section-about')`.

Comment: That works, kind of, it scrolls and stops briefly where I want it to, but then it jumps down again to where it did before... see here for example www.thisisrobot.co.uk/ if you click "work" you'll see what I mean

Comment: Ah I see. That will be because your link `#` tags match the ids of the divs you are scrolling to. The jump you mention is the browsers default behavior. I will amend my answer with a potential fix but you will have to change the div ids for it to work.

Comment: How would the scroll work if I changed the ID's though? Don't the divs need to have the same ID that the links link to?

Comment: I thought they would but apparently not - I edited the ids in chrome dev tools and it worked quite happily.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for giving it a go

Comment: @DeanElliott - Does it work if you make the changes to the html or not? There is something else I can try if it doesn't.

Comment: Like you, it works if I change it in Firebug, but if I change the actual markup it doesn't work...